# Javascript Form is not sending

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.cipslimoshuttle.com/quote -

I have a form here that was working for past year but all of sudden forms are not being sent anymore.  I have not made any changes to the site at all.  Here is the the javascript related to the form.

```
  //forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'5000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'info@cipslimoshuttle.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea,select',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'},
                        ".address":{rx:/.{5}/,target:'textarea'},
                        ".zipcode":{rx:/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/,target:'input'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$(label).val();
                        return val.length?val:'nope';
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        //alert("here");
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        //alert("here1");
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length) {
                            //alert('here2');
                            var data1={
                                    fname:_.getValFromLabel('#txtFirstname'),
                                    lname:_.getValFromLabel('#txtLastname'),
                                    title:_.getValFromLabel('#txtTitle'),
                                    company:_.getValFromLabel('#txtCompany'),
                                    address:_.getValFromLabel('#txtAddress'),
                                    city:_.getValFromLabel('#txtCity'),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel('#cmbState'),
                                    zipcode:_.getValFromLabel('#txtZip'),
                                    dayphone:_.getValFromLabel('#txtDayPhone'),
                                    nightphone:_.getValFromLabel('#txtNightPhone'),
                                    besttime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtBestTime'),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEmail'),
                                    stype:_.getValFromLabel('#cmbServiceType'),
                                    edesc:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEventDescription'),
                                    edate:_.getValFromLabel('#dtpEventDate'),
                                    estime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEStartTime'),
                                    eetime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEEndTime'),
                                    cdesc:_.getValFromLabel('#txtContractDescription'),
                                    cdate:_.getValFromLabel('#dtpContractDate'),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                }
//                              alert(data1.edate);
                            $.ajax({    
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:data1,
                                success: function(data){
                                    //alert("here ");
                                    _.showFu()
                                },
                                error:function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                                    //alert("error "+xhr.responseText+' '+textStatus+' '+error);
        $(".success").html(xhr.responseText+' '+textStatus+' '+error+' there was an error in sending the email. please try again later!');
                                },
                                complete:function(){
                                    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('.success').offset().top-30}, 'slow');
                                }
                            })  
                            } // of if  
                            else { alert($('.'+_.invalidCl).length); }  
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#contact-form').forms({
        ownerEmail:'info@cipslimoshuttle.com'
    })
})
```

Comment: What does the html/javascript look like?

Comment: Unrelated to your question entirely, but your email link is broken. You have it pointed to "#" instead of "mailto:youremail@example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Your form lacks an action attribute to tell it where to send to, and your Submit button is not actually a form submit button, but instead an A tag (a link). You need to figure out where the form used to submit, and set that to the action of the form tag, and then change `<a href="#" class="btn-3" data-type="submit">Send</a>` to something more like `<input class="btn-3" type="submit" value="Send">`

What might have happened is that there used to be JavaScript that handled the submission of the form. I see no JavaScript anywhere that does that, but instead of making the changes I described above, you could also re-write the JavaScript that might have made the form work in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your `forms_contact1.js` file and see the issue when debugging:

```
,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length) {
                        var data1={
                                fname:_.getValFromLabel('#txtFirstname'),
                                lname:_.getValFromLabel('#txtLastname'),
                                title:_.getValFromLabel('#txtTitle'),
                                company:_.getValFromLabel('#txtCompany'),
                                address:_.getValFromLabel('#txtAddress'),
                                city:_.getValFromLabel('#txtCity'),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel('#cmbState'),
                                zipcode:_.getValFromLabel('#txtZip'),
                                dayphone:_.getValFromLabel('#txtDayPhone'),
                                nightphone:_.getValFromLabel('#txtNightPhone'),
                                besttime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtBestTime'),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEmail'),
                                stype:_.getValFromLabel('#cmbServiceType'),
                                edesc:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEventDescription'),
                                edate:_.getValFromLabel('#dtpEventDate'),
                                estime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEStartTime'),
                                eetime:_.getValFromLabel('#txtEEndTime'),
                                cdesc:_.getValFromLabel('#txtContractDescription'),
                                cdate:_.getValFromLabel('#dtpContractDate'),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            }
                        $.ajax({    
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data:data1,
                            success: function(data){
                                _.showFu()
                            },
                            error:function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    $(".success").html(xhr.responseText+' '+textStatus+' '+error+' there was an error in sending the email. please try again later!');
                                _.showFu()
                            },
                            complete:function(){
                                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('.success').offset().top-30}, 'slow');
                            }
                        })  
                        } // of if  
                        else { }//alert($('.'+_.invalidCl).length); }
```

the if statement is returning false here: `if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)` and I'm not sure quite what that is checking but maybe you have some insight and this can give you some direction.